# Identify bundle containing PC remakes of several Sega-related titles

Tags: game-identification

Around the year 2012 I got a CD called "Clone Games CD" in Brazil, which is a bundle of games. It included several games packaged as Windows executables and an AutoPlay launcher for browing and launching the games, which seem to be remakes and emulations of classic games released to Sega. I recall it includes titles such as Streets of Rage (a spin-off fan-game; I'm not entirely sure it's SoR though), Dragon's Trap (a remake by Vile1011 ([link to SMSPower topic](https://www.smspower.org/forums/10266-DragonsCurseWBIIITheDragonsTrap))), Sonic 3D Blast and a helicopter game I forgot the name of.

I'd like to know if anyone happens to know the origin of the "game bundle" software used by this CD. I've picture of one of the games included by this bundle, but I don't have a picture of the CD or bundle software itself.

(I know this community accepts game identification when you've pictures of the game asked; in this case I'm giving pictures of samples of games contained in this bundle (which I referred to as "Clone Games CD"))

This is Dragon's Trap (a remake of Dragon's Curse for PCEngine). I say that it's related to Sega because Dragon's Curse for PCEngine is a Hudson Soft version of the Master System or Game Gear version of Wonderboy III: The Dragon's Trap (which got a remake by Lizard Cube in 2016).

(If it's not clear, the following pictures belong to games from the bundle. It's not anything else. You can find the downloads in the SMSPower post above.)

[image: Dragon's Trap (1)]

[image: Dragon's Trap (2)]

Here is also a YouTube series of the game:

Appreciate any help on finding this bundle!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 1.) It is not a game ID question, but rather a game *CD* ID question. 2.) The media provided is not of the game CD or its autoplay launcher or game bundle software, so this is basically asking to identify from a description of what OP can recall from memory, which is [not on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info).

Comment: @galacticninja Concerning #2: it is, I asked the OP, and they are from the games themselves: the title in the first screenshot is apparently how it actually looks in-game (they didn't even bother changing the title graphics :). I think concern #1 requires a Meta post, but since it must be very obscure, I wonder if these questions every will receive any helpful answers.

Comment: @galacticninja Your 2nd point is wrong as Joachim pointed out. I edited my post early to imply that the images belong to games in the bundle.

Comment: I understand that the images are screenshots of the games in the bundle, but if I understand your question correctly, you're looking to identify the bundle or game CD they're on, not the games themselves. Arqade's game identification policy is: 1.) Identify games, not game bundles / game CDs, and 2.) You must have media/screenshots of the game itself, or in this case, the bundle software or game CD itself. You don't have any media or screenshots of the bundle software / autoplay launcher or the CD itself (what you're looking for).

Comment: @galacticninja In the "on-topic" guidelines at the help-center (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I only read that are prohibited _Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone._ It doesn't seem to prohibit bundle identification I guess?

Comment: @Joachim and `@Matheus Dias de Souza I made a discussion about this question on [meta] to clarify if it is in accordance with our game identification policy: [Should we allow an identification question for a game CD or game bundle that lacks a media or screenshot of the game CD or game bundle itself?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16675/4797)